# Localhost working while virtual host not woking

Tags: php, laravel, apache, wamp

I have installed wamp on C:/wamp64/ folder

I have created a virtual host called sampleapp.dev. But when I access it It says "This site can’t be reached".

my httpd-vhosts file

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sampleapp.dev
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/sampleapp/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1  localhost

127.0.0.1 sampleapp.dev
::1  sampleapp.dev
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart your server after applying above changes?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Windows also caches the hosts file, try rebooting or run `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: I rebooted the machine. But still not working

Comment: 1) Did you set the privilege of sampleapp.dev, like what you did for localhost? Try some simple setting like `Require all granted `       2) Did you remove the `#` before `NameVirtualHost *:80`?

Comment: Hi Phil. Can you tell in which files I have to do the above 1) & 2)

Comment: @tha07, all I mentioned is the `httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Comment: @Phil, I have included the actual file above.And I tried 1). Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sampleapp.dev
  ServerAlias sampleapp.dev
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/sampleapp/public"
</VirtualHost>


<Directory "C:/wamp64/www/sampleapp/public">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

my setting
it's working

Comment: I pasted the above code in httpd-vhosts file. But its not working for me

Comment: what kind of error code ? 404  or 403

see a \apache\logs\access.log or error.log

Comment: This site can’t be reached
sampleapp.dev refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: it's maybe some Module not installed
for example mysql.. 
and .. if you setup the laravel framework ,  You did not set up the .env file.
then you didn't install the composer

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the Definition of the localhost Virtual Host, you need more than just the name of the VH defined, you also have to tell Apache who is allowed to access your new Virtual Host.

The `<Directory...>` block tell Apache this, specifically the `Require local` piece, but the other parameters also tell Apache useful information about whats allowed to be done in this new VH.

Try the below amendment.

> I have changed `sampleapp.dev` to `sampleapp.test`. This is because if you ever use the Chrome browser, the `.dev` tLD does some odd things now. Google bought the `.dev` tLD and Chrome now will try and enforce the use of SSL (https) on all `.dev` tLD's. Simple solution it to just use something else like `.local` or `.test`

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sampleapp.test
  ServerAlias www.sampleapp.test
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/sampleapp/public"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/sampleapp/public/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As I use `.test` instead of `.dev` yo will also have to change your HOSTS file accordingly, and then reboot or refresh your dnscache like this from a command window started using "Run as Administrator".

> Also avoid using `Require all granted` unless you actually want to allow the universe into your server. If your router blocks port 80, which they do by default nothing can actually get into your WAMPServer. But the second you decide you want to show a friend your nice new site and Port Forward port 80 to your WAMPServer PC, all sites that use `Require all granted` will become visible. Best to make that change only on the site you really want to be visible from the internet.

```
>net stop dnscache
>net start dnscahce
```